# Redirect a user on form submit based on a value in a radio button in the form

Tags: javascript, jquery

**I need to make a simple form** that is submitted using javascript to redirect a user to the correct page.

It has a list of radio buttons, and **on submit** I need to redirect the user to a page URL specified for each radio button.

Looking something like this:

[image]

I found a javascript using jquery to do this, but that is triggered on a radio button click. I need to **have a submit button**.

I thought is would be easy to do, and probably is, but somehow I can not find the solution.

This is the code I play with (I found the code elsewhere on SO, and this works. But there is no "Submit" button.):

```
I value the most:
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="redirect" value="http://example.com/food"><span>eating food</span><br>
  <input type="radio" name="redirect" value="http://example.com/kids"><span>play with my kids</span><br>
  <input type="radio" name="redirect" value="http://example.com/fishing"><span>go fishing</span><br>
  <input type="radio" name="redirect" value="http://example.com/stackoverflow"><span>answer StackOverflow questions</span><br>
</form>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('input[type="radio"]').on('click', function() {
     window.location = $(this).val();
});
</script>
```

I should probably be able to use this: https://api.jquery.com/submit/ BUT I haven't understood how to both trigger the submit and get the correct radio value at the same time, and then redirect.

Can I use the above code somehow, or do I need to make this with a totally different approach?

I tried with this:

```
I value the most:
<form id="mychoice">
  <input type="radio" name="redirect" value="http://example.com/food"><span>eating food</span><br>
  <input type="radio" name="redirect" value="http://example.com/kids"><span>play with my kids</span><br>
  <input type="radio" name="redirect" value="http://example.com/fishing"><span>go fishing</span><br>
  <input type="radio" name="redirect" value="http://example.com/stackoverflow"><span>answer StackOverflow questions</span><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>


<script>
$( "#mychoice" ).submit(function( event ) {
window.location = $('input[type="radio"]:checked').val();
});
</script>
```

The idea was to open the window location with the value I get from the checked radio button. This might be totally wrong way to do it. Didn't work... :-)

Comment: Why are you using a form? Do you want to post data to those addresses? If not, why don't you just use an anchor tag?

Comment: It is my customer that has specified they want it like this. They want it to look and act like a regular form with radio buttons. They don't want it to submit before a user actually click a submit button.

Comment: You just need to prevent the default submit event. Try `event.preventDefault()` in submit event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is a bit off.  Try the following:

```
$('input[name="redirect"]:checked').val();
```

This JSFiddle might help:

https://jsfiddle.net/yufnuwc6/2/

Comment: That worked well. Just to add to the answer (for new reader's sake) I added 'window.location = loc;  ' to add the redirect. Thank you @Justin Ober

Comment: Is there a reason why you would suggest using name for selecting rather than type?

Comment: Hmm.. On my test (local) the above worked. But when adding it to a live site on a live domain, it didn't. Even though ´ event.preventDefault();´ is added, it still submits to ´?redirect=http%3A%2F%2F´ in stead of opening a new site. Any ideas?

Comment: Put a `return false;` at the bottom of the submit function

Comment: Thank you. I tested but it didnt´'t work. I have researched more and it looks like there is some other javascript on that specific page that makes it handle like it does. I have tried to edit selector and var name, but it still act weird. it's javascript that is added into the website's theme.

Answer (score 0):

You can give this a try

```
$( "#mychoice" ).submit(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.location = $('input[type="radio"]:checked').val();
});
```

Comment: That somehow worked. It redirected to for instance 
'http://example.com/index.php?redirect=http%3A%2F%2Fmydomain.com%2Ffood'  
Meaning it tried to redirect, but didn't redirect to a new domain.

Comment: Because you were not giving any action to the form, you will have to handle the submit action by explicitly, which you already did. All you need to do is just tell the browser, you don't have to do what you do by default, so event.preventDefault()

Comment: Good to know it worked. It would redirect as per your values.

Answer (score 0):

use **button** instead of **submit**

`<input type="button" id="submit" value="Go">
</form>`

`<script>`

```
$( "#submit" ).click(function( event ) {
window.location = $('input[type="radio"]:checked').val();
});
```

`</script>`